# NodeJS: How to handle process out of memory error on large xlsx file parsing

Tags: excel, node.js, mongodb, out-of-memory

I am using nodejs to parse xlsx files as cell by cell and the parsed cell values will be stored in mongodb.

It is working fine for small excel files which is sized less than 3MB. But in case of more than 3MB, the node application was crashed by throwing an error as "**CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory**".

Used technologies:
Nodejs: v0.8.22,
MongoDB: 2.2.4

System Config:
OS: Ubuntu 12.04,
Memory: 4GB,
Processor: Intel I5

My steps to parse and store the xlsx data into mongodb:

1. Unzip a uploaded xlsx file.
2. Reading the styles, shared Strings, sheets, cells of each sheets and defined names from the extracted xml files of the uploaded xlsx file and saving those read values into an JS object.
3. Then save the read values into mongodb collections by iterating the values on the JS object.

Based on my knowledge STEP2 is causing the out of memory error because I am storing the entire xlsx values in a single JS object?.

Please provide some idea to change the way of the above process or some other valuable way to handle this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: This is unlikely to fix your problem 100%, but maybe updating Node to 0.10.16 fix some memory management problems?

Comment: We can't be of general help as you haven't included code -- it's very likely you're allocating a lot of memory for each document. Maybe you're trying to load the entire XLSX file into memory as a DOM structure?

Comment: Yes, here I am reading the entire xlsx file into a JS object and then I am storing it into the mongodb. I know it is not a good way to do. Can you please provide some good way to parse a xml data of xlsx and store it into mongodb which should avoid the out of memory error.

Comment: gustavohenke, WiredPrairie, please find my additional information in the description area above and provide your suggestion on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to start node with

`node --max-old-space-size=3000 app`

to increase the max mem to 3 GB. However, the default memory limit of node is 512 MB on 32 bit systems and 1 GB on 64 bit (according to https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ). If you hit these limits when parsing a 3 MB excel file, that sound seriously odd - might be a memory leak. Maybe you want to post the code?

Btw, Node 0.8 is not exactly a the latest and greatest... Maybe you should also try to update to a more recent version.

Comment: If I increase the memory size to 3GB, it may cause issues for more than 20+ MB sized xlsx file parsing. So I need a good way to handle this problem which allow files which have any size. Please find my additional info in the description section(Edited) about my way of parsing the xlsx data and provide your thoughts on that. Thanks

Comment: You need to post the relevant !code!, not a vague description of what you are doing. Also provide an example xslx file. Finally: You are talking about unzipping the xslx and some resulting xml. What's that about? Is this the xslx variant which uses xml internally? How do you parse it? Do you use some library?